# Simple RootAction plugin in Jenkins not working

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I've just started developing plugins in jenkins and tried to implement a root action by writing a plugin which implements RootAction. From the documentation of this interface (http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/?hudson/model/RootAction.html) it seems very easy compared to other plugins but I'm not getting it to work..

Here is my class which implements RootAction:

```
@Extension
public class MultiActionView implements RootAction {

    public String getIconFileName() {
        return "/plugins/multi-action-view/images/24x24/myPicture.png";
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "My RootAction";
    }

    public String getUrlName() {
        return "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";
    }

}
```

I see that my plugin is installed but nothing shows in the sidepanel despite it says in the documentation that the rootaction will be added automatically. I've tried with and without an index.jelly file in the appropriate folder of my project but with no positive results.

Does anyone have any idea of why this plugin is not showing or can come with a working example of how to create a simple root action in jenkins? Thanks!

// Bogge